# Block Public IPs with APIM based on header

Tags: azure-api-management, apim

Because APIM sits behind an Application Gateway, it will only see traffic as coming from the app gateway, so I do not believe the simple ip-filter policy will work. App gateway does add the original source IP to the `x-original-host` header though.

I am new to APIM policy and do not know how to build logic into it. What I want to do is IF the x-forwarded for value IS in a private IP, allow...else, deny. I see that policy expressions are written in C#, which I know nothing about.

Was thinking something like this

```
<policies>
  <inbound>
      <base />
          <check-header name="" x-original-host="" failed-check-error-message="" ignore-case="true">
              <value>This is where I need to go through the list of private IP ranges</value>
          </check-header>
  </inbound>
  [...]
</policies>
```

That could can be completely wrong too. My intent is to create rule that allows private IPs only, and denies everything else. Here are the private IPs to allow:

Class A: 10.0.0.0 to 10.255.255.255
Class B: 172.16.0.0 to 172.31.255.255
Class C: 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.255.255

Answer (score 0):

See this [Filter on request IP Address when using an Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/policies/filter-ip-addresses-when-using-appgw)